# "All the employees working in this office, but , James have a university degree." Why do we use two commas before and after "but"?

Tags: punctuation

Why are the two commas before and after "but" used in the following sentence?
"  All the employees working in this office,but,James have a university degree."

Comment: Where did the sentence originally come from? It does not appear to be grammatically correct-- the commas shouldn't be there, as you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: That looks wrong to me.  Where did you see it?

Comment: I have a feeling that the commas are being used **(incorrectly)** to emphasize "but". If so, this is non-standard and not recommended. If possible, emphasis should be added using *italics* or **bold** text. If not possible, there are other options but commas are **not** one of them.

Comment: @Catija On a related note, commas also can't be used (correctly) to indicate a verbal pause when there's no grammatical reason for having a comma. We often read commas out loud as a pause, but pauses and commas are not the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

The base of your sentence is

> All the employees working in this office have a university degree.

the exception is James. So what to do with him?
The exception clause can be offset by commas

> All the employees working in this office, ***but James***, have a university degree.
>   All the employees, ***but James***, working in this office have a university degree.
>   All the employees working in this office have a university degree ***but James***.

Alternatively, one can leave the commas out

> All the employees working in this office ***but James*** have a university degree.

Having the commas only around "but" is incorrect since the meaning that's being conveyed is

> but James

Comment: Additional detail: In your examples where the clause is offset by commas, this is a **parenthetical**. Instead of commas, you could use parentheses or em dashes.